# How to create ordered numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to create two columns (row, column) in a data frame that contains ordered numbers based on the value. For example the value is 128,
Something like that:
[image]

so the number of rows will be 128 * 128, if 256 then 256*256 and so on

Comment: Homework should be done on your own, or for a fee, using stackoverflow for this -  bad manners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested for loop:

```
x,y = [],[]
for i in range(1,129):
    for j in range(1,129):
        x.append(j)
        y.append(i)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```

Result:

```
         x    y
0        1    1
1        2    1
2        3    1
3        4    1
4        5    1
...    ...  ...
16379  124  128
16380  125  128
16381  126  128
16382  127  128
16383  128  128
```